# What is the maximal value of subsets of $B$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$$A = \{1,2,3,4\}$$
$$C = \{1,2,3,4\{1.2\},\{3,4\}$$

$$A \subset B \subset C$$

- What is the maximal number of subsets of $B$?

Okay, let me interpret this question. So, if $A \subset B$, then $\{1,2,3,4\}$ must be involved in our subset. According to this, I've found $4$ from $2^2$. However, that seems wrong on my textbook. Can you explain why?

Comment: @bof probably "number" instead of "value".

Comment: Yes, that's number. Sorry for my grammar mistake.

Comment: @bof I think that you're right. Ah the question was wrong!!

Comment: Please see new edit. I had written it wrong :/